# is it possible to use a single .html to generate multiple pages with different div ids and data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dojo

I'm using the dojo library to implement a new feature.

I've got a single dojo template in javascript and a single HTML file for creating
multiple views with different ids and data

Is this possible to achieve in the dojo? I know it may be possible in react.

**Sample dojo class**

```
define([
"dojo/text!./xlines.html",
"dojo/domReady!"],
function(mainTemplate){
    return declare([],{
        templateString: mainTemplate,
        fun1:function(){
        },
        funx:function(){
        }
          });
});
```

**sample HTML file used(**xlines.html**) **

```
<div class="centerPanel mqGenericGridCenterPanel"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
    data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
    <div id='lines5-operate-sidebar' style="width: 750px;"></div>

    <div class="mq-page" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0;">

        <div id ="p1-line1" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; min-height: 176px;">
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="mq__holder" style="padding: 0px; min-height: 156px; min-width: 270px;">
                        <div style="padding: 0px; min-width: 270px;">
                            <img class="productImageHolder1" style="max-height: 154px; max-width: 270px; display: block; margin: auto;"></img>
                        </div>
                        <div id='5linesOpDash1' style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"><canvas></canvas> </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expected to create multiple views with different data using these templates.
I've tried to change ids such as 5linesOpDash1 in javascript with page numbers, so they become 5linesOpDash11.but I'm realising this may not even possible in plain javascript.